# Allow for configurable model validations using separate files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I'm working on a Rails 3 app that uses MongoDB. As such, new keys (i.e. fields or columns from SQL-based DBs) can be added to models on the fly and without the need for any migrations or similar overhead. I am using the MongoMapper ORM.

I have a model, `EmailTemplate` that takes several of its keys from a YAML file in the config directory of the app. The thought behind this is that the app is *fully* generic and new use cases only require the modification of configuration files rather than application code.

This is working fine. Now, I want to add validations for several of the keys. Ideally, since the keys are created from a configuration file, the validations should also be created from a configuration file, maintaining the reusability of the app.

I have tried adding a file `email_template_validations.rb` to config, which defines a class like this:

```
class EmailTemplate::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    validates :countries, :presence => true
    validates :languages, :presence => true
    ...
end
```

Then in my model, I am doing `require config/email_template_validations`. Unfortunately, this is where it breaks down, and I receive a `LoadError` saying:

```
Expected proj_dir/app/models/email_template.rb to define EmailTemplate
```

So, **the question**: Am I fighting best practices here? Is there a better way to do this? How can I use validations from a separate file?

Comment: not an answer to your question, but the error you're getting is somewhat of a separate issue.  It's complaining because you have a class `EmailTemplate` and in this file you're trying to define a module by the same name.